# Modify API permissions in Shopify

Tags: ruby-on-rails, permissions, shopify

I have an existing app for a shopify store and it only reads products with the API. However, I want to add new features which will make use of metafields edit/update/read api. How can I modifiy my api permissions to give me access to the shops' metafields read/write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access to metafields is governed by access to the parent object. For example, if you want to write product metafields then you should add the `write_products` [OAuth scope](https://help.shopify.com/api/guides/authentication/oauth#scopes) to your app.

Answer (score 2):

You need to unintall your app first. In detail, follow 3 steps below:

- Uninstall your app.
- Inside the stuff of your app-codes, modify SCOPE as you want to. Read more about SCOPE on Shopify.com: https://help.shopify.com/api/guides/authentication/oauth#scopes
- Install your app again, make sure on install-screen, the new-scope should bee applied.

Comment: Thanks Nguyen, I have followed same steps and it is working now.